# Save path for resized img PHP

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

Here's my issue, i did this :

```
        $fichierIMG = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        $tailleSource = getimagesize($fichierIMG);

        $image_type = $tailleSource[2]; 

        if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {   
        $imageSource = imagecreatefromjpeg($fichierIMG);  
        $imgResize = redimension($imageSource,$tailleSource[0],$tailleSource[1]);
        imagejpeg($imgResize,$_FILES['image']['name'] . "_thump.jpg");
        }

        elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
        $imageSource = imagecreatefrompng($fichierIMG); 
        $imgResize = redimension($imageSource,$tailleSource[0],$tailleSource[1]);
        imagepng($imgResize,$_FILES['image']['name'] . "_thump.png");
        }

        function redimension($imageSource,$width,$height) {
            $img_width =200;
            $img_height =200;
            $imgResize=imagecreatetruecolor($img_width,$img_height);
            imagecopyresampled($imgResize,$imageSource,0,0,0,0,$img_width,$img_height, $width,$height);
            return $imgResize;
            }
```

But my file with "_thump.xxx" doesn't appear in my uploads folder, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making all your changes based on a temporary file.

also, you never specify an uploads directory anywhere:

`imagejpeg($imgResize,$_FILES['image']['name'] . "_thump.jpg");`
should probably be
`imagejpeg($imgResize,"uploads/".$_FILES['image']['name'] . "_thump.jpg");`

Wouldn't hurt to use move_uploaded_file to ensure that the file is actually uploaded correctly too.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Thank you, i did use move_uploaded_file, but i didn't past all my code, i can if it have any interest but i wasn't sure :)

Comment: I'd say the issue is due to missing "uploads/" in the file path, so should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

here are things i did to fix your code locally.

1. I used move_uploaded_file to move the file to "image/" directory you can put it where ever you want.
   1.1) create $uploaddir variable
   1.2) create $uploadfile variable
2. I made sure that setting in php.ini for upload_max_filesize set to 128M in my case because lot's of software were running at the same time.
3. I stripped off .png or .jpg name from the names using str_replace() function.

//create a $uploaddir variable and initialize it with the folder you want in my case image/

```
$uploaddir="image/";
```

//create another variable to append upload directory and file name as following

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

//move the file uploaded as following

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
}

else {
    echo "Failed to move file to required directory!\n";
}
```

//the following is the final code you can copy paste and edit only the $uploaddir variable

```
$uploaddir="image/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
}

else {
    echo "Failed to move file to required directory!\n";
}
$fichierIMG="$uploaddir".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tailleSource = getimagesize($fichierIMG);
$image_type = $tailleSource[2]; 

if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {   
    $imageSource = imagecreatefromjpeg($fichierIMG);  
    $imgResize = redimension($imageSource,$tailleSource[0],$tailleSource[1]);
    imagejpeg($imgResize,str_replace(".jpg","",$_FILES['image']['name']).        
"_thump.jpg");//str_replace will strip off the .jpg extension
}

else if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
    $imageSource = imagecreatefrompng($fichierIMG); 
    $imgResize = redimension($imageSource,$tailleSource[0],$tailleSource[1]);
    imagepng($imgResize,str_replace(".png","",$_FILES['userfile']['name']) . 
    "_thump.png");//str_replace will strip off the .png extension
}

function redimension($imageSource,$width,$height) {
    $img_width =200;
    $img_height =200;
    $imgResize=imagecreatetruecolor($img_width,$img_height);
    imagecopyresampled($imgResize,$imageSource,0,0,0,0,$img_width,$img_height, 
    $width,$height);
    return $imgResize;
}
```

//let us know if it worked using the triangle